# htaccess does not work properly

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my WebServer I have a htaccess file which looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

So all calls to my WebServer are redirected to the index.php file in my root directory with a path parameter which holds the requested file. Now look at these two calls:

```
domain.com/test/blub.php        works -> path = test/blub.php
domain.com/test/                does not work -> path should be test
```

How can I achieve the the second call also works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this condition from your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

As this is skipping all real directories from this rule.

Use your rule as:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Works very good. But now the path parameter is showen in the url. Can I cut it off in some way?

Comment: Now if I call domain.com/test it is not redirected to the index.php file

Comment: I'm sorry you are right. I had an error in my PHP script :/ sorry for that.